# Concat str to 3 digits

Tags: python, django, sorting, concatenation

What is attempted to achieve is to sort a column in the changelist_view. The column consists of numbers with either 001-001-001 or 001-001-A-001 type. Used to @property method to build these numbers from integer fields, from several models.

Now, sorting is quite cumbersome. After research on this site / django docs came across the annotate method, with conditions and Concat function. This works (%03d in below code is eliminated) and sorts, but rather than 3 digit numbers it yields in 1-1-1 or 900-1-A-1 type numbers. This is not the targeted sorting.

Converting it to three digits gives the error: '%d format: a number is required, not str'

Is it possible to convert the separate fields to three digits and achieve the sorting?

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    q = Asset.objects.annotate(
        annotated_value=Case(
            When(subcategory__number__isnull=False, 
                then=Concat(
                '%03d' % ('subcategory__category__parent__number'),
                '%03d' % ('subcategory__category__number'), 
                'subcategory__number', 
                '%03d' % ('number'),
                )
            ),
            When(subcategory__number__isnull=True, 
                then=Concat(
                    '%03d' % ('category__parent__number'), 
                    '%03d' % ('category__number'), 
                    '%03d' % ('number')
                    )
                ),
            output_field=CharField(),
            )
        )
    return q
```

Comment: As the error says, the `'%03d'` formatter will only work if you pass it an integer, but the data you are fetching from the database is a string. You probably need to use a regular expression or something to parse the string.

Comment: thanks solarissmoke for your response. I've tried to parse it to integer (int()), yields in the following : invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'subcategory__category__parent__number'. How would a regular expression be applied in this context? (im still quite a rookie on python)

Comment: Hmm, looking at it more closely I don't think this approach will work at all. `'%03d' % ('subcategory__category__parent__number'),` is actually trying to convert the string `'subcategory__category__parent__number'` into a number - not the database field that it represents. If you need to query the database based on the first three numbers then I would suggest you need to rethink how you store the data - those three numbers should be in a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again, solarissmoke. Did not restructure the model, but indeed came to the conclusion i was walking the wrong path with get_queryset. Solved it with a list filter, which does exactly what is needed, albeit without column sorting.

```
class AssetListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

title = 'Asset'
parameter_name = 'asset'

def lookups(self, request, model_admin):

    q = []

    for asset in Asset.objects.all():
        if asset.subcategory:
            q.append(
                (
                    str(asset.id),
                    '%03d-%03d-%s-%03d - %s' % (
                        asset.subcategory.category.parent.number, 
                        asset.subcategory.category.number, 
                        asset.subcategory.number, 
                        asset.number, 
                        asset.full_name
                        )
                    )
                )
        else:
            q.append(
                (
                    str(asset.id),
                    '%03d-%03d-%03d - %s' % (
                        asset.category.parent.number, 
                        asset.category.number, 
                        asset.number, 
                        asset.full_name
                    )
                )
            )

    list = sorted(q, key=lambda x: x[1])
    return list
    print(q)

def queryset(self, request, queryset):

    q = Q()
    if self.value() is not None:
        q = Q(asset__id=int(self.value()))
    return queryset.filter(q)
```